# Including LaTeX symbols with MathJax inside Google Charts?

Tags: javascript, google-visualization, mathjax

Within a tree diagram generated with [Google Charts](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/orgchart) I would like to include LaTeX symbols generated with MathJax. Using the $ $ command that normally works throughout my HTML file, I am unable to reproduce these symbols within the javascript code of the diagram itself. Is there any way to do this?

The following jsfiddle sums it all up: http://jsfiddle.net/jqzup01b/

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/main.js"></script>
<script type="text/x-mathjax-config">
MathJax.Hub.Config({
MatchWebFonts: {
    matchFor: {
      "HTML-CSS": true,
      NativeMML: false,
      SVG: false
    },
    fontCheckDelay: 2000,
    fontCheckTimeout: 30 * 1000
  },


jax: ["input/TeX","output/HTML-CSS"],
  "HTML-CSS": { linebreaks: { automatic: true },  matchFontHeight: true, scale: 90 },
         SVG: { linebreaks: { automatic: true }, matchFontHeight: true},
    tex2jax: {inlineMath: [['$','$']]}
});
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML"> </script>
<script type="text/javascript">
      google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["orgchart"]});
      google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
      function drawChart() {
        var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
        data.addColumn('string', 'Name');
        data.addColumn('string', 'Manager');
        data.addColumn('string', 'ToolTip');

        data.addRows([
          [{v:'Mike', f:'One<div style="color:grey; font-style:italic" w></div>'}, '', ''],
          [{v:'Jim', f:'Two<div style="color:grey; font-style:italic; background: white; width: 100px;">$can i haz LaTeX here$<div>'}, 'Mike', ''],
          [{v:'Alice', f:'Three<div style="color:grey; font-style:italic">$\in$<div>'}, 'Mike', '']

        ]);

        var chart = new google.visualization.OrgChart(document.getElementById('chart_span'));
        chart.draw(data, {allowHtml:true});
      }

</script>

    This is not LaTeX.<br>
    $\int ( This \, is).$

    <span id="chart_span">  
</span>
```

Comment: Note from the future: cdn.mathjax.org is nearing its end-of-life, check mathjax.org/cdn-shutting-down for migration tips.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the chart will be loaded asynchronously, MathJax's initial typesetting pass will already be over by the time the chart arrives.

So you need to trigger another typesetting call (which will look for new content) by adding

```
        MathJax.Hub.Queue(["Typeset",MathJax.Hub]);
```

to your `drawChart` function, see the snippet below and [the MathJax documentation for more](http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/typeset.html).

PS: Keep in mind that TeX strings in JavaScript need lots of escaping, e.g, `\\in`.

```html
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/main.js"></script>
<script type="text/x-mathjax-config">
MathJax.Hub.Config({
MatchWebFonts: {
    matchFor: {
      "HTML-CSS": true,
      NativeMML: false,
      SVG: false
    },
    fontCheckDelay: 2000,
    fontCheckTimeout: 30 * 1000
  },


jax: ["input/TeX","output/HTML-CSS"],
  "HTML-CSS": { linebreaks: { automatic: true },  matchFontHeight: true, scale: 90 },
         SVG: { linebreaks: { automatic: true }, matchFontHeight: true},
 tex2jax: {inlineMath: [['$','$']]}
});
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.0/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML"> </script>
<script type="text/javascript">
      google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["orgchart"]});
      google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
      function drawChart() {
        var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
        data.addColumn('string', 'Name');
        data.addColumn('string', 'Manager');
        data.addColumn('string', 'ToolTip');

        data.addRows([
          [{v:'Mike', f:'One<div style="color:grey; font-style:italic" w></div>'}, '', ''],
          [{v:'Jim', f:'Two<div style="color:grey; font-style:italic; background: white; width: 100px;">$can i haz LaTeX here$<div>'}, 'Mike', ''],
          [{v:'Alice', f:'Three<div style="color:grey; font-style:italic">$\in$<div>'}, 'Mike', '']
    
        ]);

        var chart = new google.visualization.OrgChart(document.getElementById('chart_span'));
        chart.draw(data, {allowHtml:true});
        MathJax.Hub.Queue(["Typeset",MathJax.Hub]);
      }
    
</script>
    
    This is not LaTeX.<br>
    $\int ( This \, is).$
    
    <span id="chart_span">  
</span>
```

Comment: Peter, do you happen to know if there is a way to have MathJax display equations in tooltips of the form "data-tooltip" as well? See for example: http://jsfiddle.net/976sb5q6/1/ 
If not I will probably end up using a jQueryUI tooltip.

Comment: I don't know enough about the Google Charts API but from a quick glance, have you tried [their HTML-Tooltips](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/customizing_tooltip_content?hl=ja#enabling_html_tooltip)? A regular tooltip cannot contain HTML (just plain text).

Comment: I'm afraid this only applies to Google Charts, whereas in this case I am trying to have a tooltip appear when certain words are hovered on throughout my webpage. There are ways around this but the data-tooltip feature was particularly suited to my needs. Regardless, I appreciate the suggestion.

Comment: Do you mean a tooltip by using plain CSS3 to grab the data attribute? Or are you using some JS library to grab it?

Comment: Plain CSS, yes. I ended up using something similar to this: http://tympanus.net/Development/TooltipStylesInspiration/ 
Had to specify a fixed width for the tooltip but it does the job and equations display properly. Thanks again for getting back to me.

Comment: Glad it worked. I don't know how plain CSS  tooltips can be made to work, actually. There surely must be a way... Interesting problem.

Comment: Edited my answer to use snippet instead of jsfiddle.