# Latex formula in google charts

Tags: javascript, html, google-visualization

A decade I am using the pair gnuplot/latex, however this time I would like something more interacting, there I am deciding to experiment the google chart.
As new player, I get a few difficulties ...

I am trying to make a scatter plot, and to each to my point attribute a "latex" formula. Following the manual of Google, I used HTML [tooltip](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/customizing_tooltip_content). I also follow the instruction of this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26050620/including-latex-symbols-with-mathjax-inside-google-charts).

I get my plot but the "latex formula" does not work [example](https://jsfiddle.net/timocafe/rLc0a0e9/#&togetherjs=sT3OcA6c8E), I just get my "latex string" like it is.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" async src="https://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-MML-AM_CHTML"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
      google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawSeriesChart);

      function drawSeriesChart() {
      var data_scalar = new google.visualization.DataTable();

      // Declare columns scala
      data_scalar.addColumn('number', 'Throughput');
      data_scalar.addColumn('number', 'Lantency');
      data_scalar.addColumn({'type': 'string', 'role': 'tooltip', 'p': {'html': true}}); // tool tip on

      // Add data.
      data_scalar.addRows([
           [28.08,4.11, createCustomHTMLContent('P_b^{10}')],
           [21.80,3.70, createCustomHTMLContent('P_b^{2}P_b^{2}P_b^{2}P_b^{2}P_b^{2}')],
           [21.81,3.70, createCustomHTMLContent('P_b^{2}P_b^{2}P_b^{2}P_b^{2}P_e^{2}')],
           [21.46,3.64, createCustomHTMLContent('P_b^{2}P_b^{2}P_b^{2}P_b^{2}P_{h^1}^{2}')],
           [21.81,3.70, createCustomHTMLContent('P_b^{2}P_b^{2}P_b^{2}P_e^{2}P_e^{2}')],
           [21.46,3.63, createCustomHTMLContent('P_b^{2}P_b^{2}P_b^{2}P_e^{2}P_{h^1}^{2}')],
           [21.65,3.65, createCustomHTMLContent('P_b^{2}P_b^{2}P_b^{2}P_{h^1}^{2}P_{h^1}^{2}')],
           [21.81,3.70, createCustomHTMLContent('P_b^{2}P_b^{2}P_e^{2}P_e^{2}P_e^{2}')],
           [21.47,3.63, createCustomHTMLContent('P_b^{2}P_b^{2}P_e^{2}P_e^{2}P_{h^1}^{2}')],
           [21.64,3.65, createCustomHTMLContent('P_b^{2}P_b^{2}P_e^{2}P_{h^1}^{2}P_{h^1}^{2}')],
           [21.64,3.60, createCustomHTMLContent('P_b^{2}P_b^{2}P_{h^1}^{2}P_{h^1}^{2}P_{h^1}^{2}')],
           [30.97,4.16, createCustomHTMLContent('P_b^{2}P_b^{4}P_b^{4}')],
           [25.85,3.87, createCustomHTMLContent('P_b^{2}P_b^{4}P_e^{4}')],
           [25.03,3.55, createCustomHTMLContent('P_b^{2}P_b^{4}P_{h^1}^{4}')],
           [25.94,3.64, createCustomHTMLContent('P_b^{2}P_b^{4}P_{h^2}^{4}')],
           [35.40,4.47, createCustomHTMLContent('P_{h^7}^{10}')],
           [32.18,4.25, createCustomHTMLContent('P_{h^7}^{8}P_b^{2}')],
           [32.17,5.90, createCustomHTMLContent('P_{h^7}^{8}P_e^{2}')],
           [32.67,6.05, createCustomHTMLContent('P_{h^7}^{8}P_{h^1}^{2}')],
           [29.28,5.83, createCustomHTMLContent('P_{h^8}^{10}')],
           [31.01,4.33, createCustomHTMLContent('P_{h^9}^{10}')]
     ]);

     var options = {
       hAxis: {title: 'Latency', minValue: 15 },
       vAxis: {title: 'Throughput'},
       tooltip: { isHtml: true }, // tool tip on
       legend: 'none',
       pointSize: 1
     };

     function createCustomHTMLContent(method){
         return ' \( '+ method+ ' \)'; //latex mode
     }

     var chart = new google.visualization.ScatterChart(document.getElementById('series_chart_div'));
     chart.draw(data_scalar, options);
     MathJax.Hub.Queue(["Typeset",MathJax.Hub]);
     }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="series_chart_div" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>
    thiw work
    \( e^x = 2 \times P_b^2 \)
  </body>
 </html>
```

It is probably basic, but my Web experience has started yesterday ...

Best,

++t